# SSIS Package runs from SSIS but not from Job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have built an SSIS Packaage that imports data on a daily basis.

i have tested it in BIDS and it runs fine, i have deployed it to the the SSIS server and it runs fine, but when i schedule it to run as a job it Errors out. i get the errors below. i've added the srvSQLagent account to the the correct group to have access to the folder that causing the problem.. am i missing something stupid here?

===================================================================

Date        03/07/2013 14:55:06
Log     Job History (Import SN2 Data)

Step ID     1
Server      STX-RPT
Job Name        Import SN2 Data
Step Name       Run Import Package
Duration        00:00:09
Sql Severity        0
Sql Message ID      0
Operator Emailed
Operator Net sent
Operator Paged
Retries Attempted       0

Message
Executed as user: INT\srvSQLagent. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.1600.1 for 32-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.
Started:  14:55:06
Error: 2013-07-03 14:55:15.69
Code: 0xC001401E
Source: Servicenet Data Import Connection manager "Downloaded"
Description: The file name "\\FILE\Groups\ISG\England\Servicenet Data\Downloaded" specified in the connection was not valid.  End Error
Error: 2013-07-03 14:55:15.69
Code: 0xC0202070
Source: Servicenet Data Import Connection manager "Downloaded"
Description: The file name property is not valid. The file name is a device or contains invalid characters.  End Error
Error: 2013-07-03 14:55:15.69
Code: 0xC0029163
Source: File System Task File System Task
Description: File or directory "\\FILE\Groups\ISG\England\Servicenet Data\Downloaded" represented by connection "Downloaded" does not exist.  End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  14:55:06
Finished: 14:55:15
Elapsed:  9 seconds.
The package execution failed.
The step failed.

Comment: Check permissions. When you run it from BIDS or from SSIS, it runs under your credentials. When you run as a job, it uses the SQLAgent user account's credentials (INT\srvSQLagent). Looks like that user can't see the file location.

Comment: And why is that file location not an absolute path? There is no guarantee AFAIK for the working directory of an SQL Job.

Comment: I have logged in as srvSQLagent and have access to the files and folders required. and its a UNC because its a network share. Mapped drives are user specific.

Answer (score 0):

The issue had arisen from using a File system task to clear a folder of all Files.

I never got to the bottom of the problem, i simply found a different method of deleting the required files.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely folder permission issue.

Please give proper rights for everyone.

Alpesh Dhori
Software Professional

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that next solution will help you:

Assume that we need to write 
**\\serv\share\dir1..\dirN\targetDir\somefile.txt** using SSIS throught SQL Agent Job and nonadmin proxy account MyDomain\TestAccount

1) MyDomain\TestAccount need read/write access to share **\\serv\share**

2) MyDomain\TestAccount needed at least FILE_READ_DATA permission for all folders (**share**,**dir1**,..**dirN**)

3) MyDomain\TestAccount needed the CHANGE rights + FILE_DELETE_CHILD permission for folder **targetDir**

(cacls should show this permissions as following:

```
DELETE
READ_CONTROL
SYNCHRONIZE
FILE_GENERIC_READ
FILE_GENERIC_WRITE
FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE
FILE_READ_DATA
FILE_WRITE_DATA
FILE_APPEND_DATA
FILE_READ_EA
FILE_WRITE_EA
FILE_EXECUTE
FILE_DELETE_CHILD
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES
FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES
```

)

Of course the full rights for **targetDir** are enough.

If **targetDir** doesn't has FILE_DELETE_CHILD permission then we see such strange behavior of flat file connection in SSIS. User MyDomain\TestAccount may doing anything with file **somefile.txt** (read,write,delete) using standard Windows tools. But SSIS Job can't overwrite this file and fail.